# Disable autocomplete for password modification form

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I've heard that now all web browsers ignore the `autocomplete="off"` attribute because it prevents users from changing the passwords to be easy to remember (and thus crack).

But for my case, I just want to disable the autocomplete functionality solely for the change password form and not for the login form. How should I do?

Here is my (simplified) code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="?page=change_pass" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="oldPass" placeholder="Current password">
        <input type="password" id="p1" name="newPass" placeholder="New password">
        <input type="password" id="p2" placeholder="Confirm new password">
        <button type="submit">Change password</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
    //This script checks if p1 == p2
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you post your code? it will be helpful for people who wants to help

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte Done, sorry for the time

Comment: Based from my experience, password type by default has no autocomplete.

Comment: And BTW, I would be keen to know if it's correct to put a GET parameter directly in the `action` attribute like I did.

Comment: Never use GET if you are using password. Please refer to this link to get the difference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: @ReyNorbertBesmonte But if the user has checked the box "Remember my password" in the browser? And I'm not using GET to transit the sensible data like the passwords, but just the name of the page to be included by the index.php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167548/discussion-between-jacopostanchi-and-rey-norbert-besmonte).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="?page=change_pass" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" name="oldPass" placeholder="Current password" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" id="p1" name="newPass" placeholder="New password" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" id="p2" placeholder="Confirm new password" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit">Change password</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
    //This script checks if p1 == p2
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```